# Using 2 External HDMI Monitors to a Macbook Pro 2017 without Mirroring External Displays

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, hdmi, big-sur

My Macbook Pro 2017 is currently connected to an external HDMI monitor through a hub. This hub occupies both USB-C ports on one side of the laptop and contains a HDMI output which is connected to the external monitor.

[image]

Can a second external monitor be connected to the Macbook pro via HDMI without having it in mirrored mode due to Mac's lack of support for MST? I am thinking of getting a USB-C to HDMI adapter and connecting this to the existing USB-C hub, will this allow the 2nd external monitor to extend instead of mirroring the first external display?

[image]

Comment: According to EveryMac your system supports two external 4K monitors: https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.3-13-mid-2017-retina-display-no-touch-bar-specs.html

Comment: @SteveChambers Thanks, does it still supporrts 2 external 4K@60 monitors if my setup does not use Thunderbolt? Also, if my setup actually using Thunderbolt?